# What exactly are arguments or parameters in java?

Tags: java, eclipse, function, methods

I'm quite new to java and am not very well versed with methods. Can someone explain to me what variables of a method are parameters and which ones aren't?

Comment: `void foo(int a, int b) { int c; }`, given `foo`. `a` and `b` are arguments (aka parameters). `c` is a local variable (and not an *argument* or a *parameter*).

Answer (score 2):

Let's say that you have the following class:

```
public class Calculator {

    public int add(int x, int y){
        return x+y;
    }
}
```

We say that the method called `add` has two parameters of type int. (`calculator` is an instance of the class `Calculator`).

When we call the method:

```
calculator.add(3,4)
```

we say that we pass to the method the arguments 3 and 4.

So we could say that parameters of a method are everything in the [signature](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) of a method. While arguments are the actual values we pass when we call the method.

Comment: I'm not a Java developer but based on other language terminology, followed up by a quick search, it seems you've reversed the meanings of the terms "argument" and "parameter".

Comment: @squint Neither me I am a Java developer. You are pretty correct. My bad :( ! Thanks :)

Comment: Slightly pedantic comment but, by convention, Java methods are lower case. Feel free to ignore me. :)

Answer (score 0):

A parameter is a variable in a method definition. When a method is called, the arguments are the data you pass into the method's parameters

Take the following example here:

```
public class Book{

    String title;

    public void setTitle(String param){
        title = param;
    }
}
```

When you call the `Book` classes method `setTitle()`

```
setTitle("The art of peace");
```

The string that you send to the method is your argument. The variable inside the method is your parameter.